# Module builder as drush plugin

Tags: drush

I thought I had installed successfully [module builder](https://drupal.org/project/module_builder) as drush plugin : typing `help mb` returns complete help story...

But when I try to use it, ie typing `mb easyresponsive_panels ctools_plugin_directory menu  --write`, it gives me the following error :

> Command mb-build needs a **higher bootstrap level to run** - you will need
>   to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this
>   command. The drush command 'mb easyresponsive_panels' could not be
>   executed. **Could not find a Drupal settings.php** file at
>   sites/default/settings.php.

I have a multi site install, this is why no sites/default/settings.php is found.

I tried to specify root and site explicitly, as per [these answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/drush-on-windows-command-pm-enable-needs-a-higher-bootstrap-level-to-run?rq=1), running  `--root=path/to/drupal --uri=mysite.com status`, this returns the correct complete status :

```
Drupal version : 7.24 
Site URI : visages_20131224:8082 
Database driver : mysql 
Database username : drupaluser 
Database name : visages_20131224 
Database : Connected 
Drupal bootstrap : Successful 
Drupal user : 
Default theme : neptune 
Administration theme : adaptivetheme_admin 
PHP executable : php.exe 
PHP configuration : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini 
PHP OS : WINNT
Drush version : 7.0-dev 
Drush configuration : 
Drush alias files : 
Drupal root : C:\Users\Thierry\Sites\visages_20131224\ 
Site path : sites/visages_20131224 
File directory path : sites/visages_20131224/files 
Temporary file directory path : c:\windows\temp
```

(my dev config : Windows 7, Acquia Dev Deskstop, Netbeans, D7)

Related Q&A didn't enlightened me yet, any help is welcome.

Comment: The normal method is to set up Drush [aliases](http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/drupal-drush-aliases-and-how-use-them), and use `drush @alias ...` to target a particular site

Comment: Many thanks for the link @Clive, I read it quickly, but don't understand how it could help in my case ? says : "drush aliases allow you to run a drush commands on your local server but actually execute the command on a remote server. " very useful indeed, but at the moment I don't have any remote install for that dev ... It's a localhost pb

Comment: Sorry, [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/ubivda) would've been better :)

Comment: Yep @Clive got it working, narrow-minded I was : @ mysite.local mb mymodule hook1 hook2 --write Please write both links as answer, both were useful. Or if you prefer I'll redact answer myself. Many thanks again

Comment: If you wouldn't mind posting your last edit as an answer (with any other steps if there were any) that would be awesome, I'm sure it would help some future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Clive comments, and as explained in [Drupal, Drush aliases and how to use them](http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/drupal-drush-aliases-and-how-use-them), I solved it as following.

Add an alias conf file named `sitename.aliases.drushrc.php` in .drush folder in your home directory :

```
/**
 * Local
 */
// The site in sites/default/
$aliases['default.local'] = array(
  'uri' => 'default',
  'root' => '/path/to/drupal',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%dump-dir' => '/tmp'
  ),
);
// The site in sites/sitename/ 
$aliases['sitename.local'] = array(
  'uri' => 'sitename_URI',
  'root' => '/path/to/drupal',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%dump-dir' => '/tmp'
  ),
);
```

Don't forget to clear cache : `drush cache-clear drush`.

Test your alias : `@sitename.local status`.

Now you can run i.e `@sitename.local mb mymodule hook1 hook2 --write`

Really powerful !

See [Drush multi-site aliases](https://coderwall.com/p/ubivda) for complete configuration of local/remote aliases